# redis data structure to store stock day return

Tags: redis

I have the stock daily return data from market, and want to put them to redis,
current data format is [stock_id, date, profit],
my most operation is to search a stock list from an interval days, e.g.
stock_id_list: (203, 512, 532), date: from '20050101' to '20151231'

If query data from mysql, it's quite slow.

I want you to help me design a redis data structure to store these data, and can query them quickly

Comment: Could you please give an example of the source data and what you expect to receive as a result of the query. It is not clear whether you want to get profit for a specific stock within the given time or something else

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sortedset. use the date as value and make others into a json as the member. When you query, use the zrangebyscore. in redis ZADD doc:

> The score values should be the string representation of a double
>   precision floating point number. +inf and -inf values are valid values
>   as well.

so you should convert the date to a number, use the timestamp or the days count form a early timepoint or change the date to a number E.g. 2017-08-11 to 20170811

One thing to notice: score could be repeated, but member cannot in sorted set,

> If a specified member is already a member of the sorted set, the score is updated and the element reinserted at the right position to ensure the correct ordering.

so you should add a field make your stock data unique, such as uuid or the timestamp you insert it into redis.

Comment: Thanks, the biggest problem I worried is the repeated value of the member, you say I can use uuid or timestamp, but it is too big compare to the equ return which is just a number, and after the query I need to split the string to get the number, which will be a big cost

Comment: As my answers said, when you store stock item into redis, you should use json dumps to convert your stock object (or dict) to a string. When you retrieve from redis, you also need loads the string to an dict to get your info you want. the serialization and deserialization is unavoidable. Becuse redis does not store complex structure . But actually the time cost is the string length, not very big as you think.